# Control visibility of multiple layers

Tags: openlayers-2

I am displaying multiple feature types using one layer in OpenLayers, like here:

```
 var **vector** = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Layer", { 
  maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1.09863,44.42907, 91.01074, 2.05840) 
  sphericalMercator: true,  
  protocol:  new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({   
  url: 'http://mydomain/geoserver/wfs', 
  featureType: **["mylayer_1","mylayer_2","mylayer_3"],** 
  featureNS: "http://mapmap.org", 
  srsName: "EPSG:3857", 
  version: "1.1.0", 
  extractAttributes: true, 
  isBaseLayer: false, 
  visibility: true 
   }) 
  });
```

now I want to make **layer_2** invisible by setVisibility(false).. but I don't know how to select it. it seems like I just can control the whole layer (**vector**).

is there any way to control visibility of these layers ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use separate OpenLayers.Layer.Vector object for each WFS-layer. For example:

```js
var mylayer_1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Layer 1", {
    ....
    featureType: "mylayer_1",
    ...
});

var mylayer_2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Layer 2", {
    ....
    featureType: "mylayer_2",
    ...
});
```